# Return an array from PHP function to Smarty

Tags: php, function, smarty, return

At the risk of self-embarrassment, could anyone tell me how to use `return` here:

```
function dayCount() {

    for ($dayBegin = 1; $dayBegin < 32; $dayBegin++)
    {
      "<option value=\"".$dayBegin."\">".$dayBegin."</option>";
    }
}
```

My issue is that I am passing this function to Smarty via

```
$dayCount = dayCount();
$smarty->assign('dayCount', $dayCount);
```

and

```
{$dayCount}
```

but instead the HTML is going straight to the buffer, right before `<html>` (thanks Hamish), not inside the HTML element I want.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build up the return statement

```
function dayCount() {
    $return = array();
    for ($dayBegin = 1; $dayBegin < 32; $dayBegin++)
    {
      $return[] = "<option value=\"".$dayBegin."\">".$dayBegin."</option>";
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Although this is building up an array like you asked. When outputting it, you would need to implode it.

```
implode('', $dayCount);
```

Or otherwise, build up a string instead of an array.

Comment: Jacob, you nailed it! Thanks so much for helping - works a treat. I had tried several versions using `return` but they always output 'array' -- `implode` was always missing!!